# Using separators in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a program that uses ";" as a seperator and extracts the url up until that point upon searching the content.

So it has the format:

```
name;surname
```

In searching the given arrays... I decided to go the extra mile and test for arrays without the ";" but this has confused the program - it has no idea of the ";" position anymore and this throws a spanner in the works!

Here is my code so far - many thanks in advance!

```
pages = 
        [
        "The first", "An;alternative;page", "Yet another page"
        ]

    u_c_pages = 
        [
        "www.cam.ac.uk;"+pages[0]
        ,
        "www.warwick.ac.uk"+pages[1]
        ,
        "www.kcl.ac.uk;"+pages[1]
        , 
        "www;"+pages[2]
        ]

    var pattern5 = prompt('5) Please enter a search term:'); 

    function url1_m1(u_c_pages,pattern)
    {

        var seperator = []; 
        var seperatorPos = [];

        if(pattern) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < u_c_pages.length; i++) 
                {

                    var found = true;
                    if((u_c_pages[i].indexOf(";"))<0)
                        {
                        found=false;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        seperator[seperator.length] = i;
                        seperatorPos[seperatorPos.length] = (u_c_pages[i].indexOf("|"));
                        }
                } 
                if(seperator.length==0)
                        {
                        return("Nothing found!");
                        }
                else
                var found2 = "";
                {
                for (var j = 0; j < seperator.length; j++) 
                        {
                        if(u_c_pages[j].substring(seperatorPos[j],u_c_pages[j].length-1).toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                            {
                            found2 = (u_c_pages[j].substring(0,seperatorPos[j]));
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                return(found2)
                }
        }
        else 
        {
        // only returned when the user decides to type in nothing
            return("Nothing entered!");
        } 
    }
    alert(url1_m1(u_c_pages,pattern5));
```

Comment: I'm confused. You said you use ; as a seperator, but your format is url|content. isn't it supposed to be url;content? Also your second element in u_c_pages is missing a ;

Comment: Is is possibly so simple as a missing double quote in the third line of your code?

Comment: Sorry everyone I've updated the code

Comment: I purposely left out the ";" to test what would happen with the first branch of code. It is designed to validate the array to see whether or not it can pick up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enjoy the power of regex:

[on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGff9/)

```
pages = ["The first", "An;alternative;page", "Yet another page"];

u_c_pages = [
  "www.lboro.ac.uk;"+pages[0],
  "www.xyz.ac.uk;"+pages[1],
  "www.xyz.ac.uk;"+pages[1], 
  "www;"+pages[2]
];

var pattern5 = prompt('5) Please enter a search term:');

function url1_m1(u_c_pages,pattern)
{
  // escape search pattern
  pattern = pattern.toLowerCase().replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
  pattern = new RegExp('^([^;]+);.*?' + pattern, 'i');

  var result = null;

  for(var i=0;i<u_c_pages.length;i++) {
    if((result = u_c_pages[i].match(pattern))) {
      return result[1];
    }
  }

  return false;
}
alert(url1_m1(u_c_pages,pattern5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.split(";") to split a string into segments. The parameter is the seperator.